# getting text associated to radio button in radiogroup

Tags: android

I have a radiogroup that i populate dynamically as follows:

```
        RadioGroup ll = new RadioGroup(this);
        ll.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

        for (int i = 1; i <= repItem.length; i++) {
            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
            rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
            rdbtn.setText(repItem[i-1]);
            ll.addView(rdbtn);
        }

        ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroupchoi)).addView(ll);
```

and i get a click event as follow where i would like to capture the text of the associated selected radio button in the radiogroup. But it is giving me nullpointerexception. Any help?

```
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            RadioGroup rChoi=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroupchoi);
            RadioButton butChoi=(RadioButton) findViewById(rChoi.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),butChoi.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the RadioButtons directly to your RadioGroup that you have in your layout, instead of creating a new RadioGroup and adding it as a child view to the existing one. So just find the RadioGroup and add RadioButtons to it, like this:

```
    RadioGroup ll = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroupchoi);
    ll.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

    for (int i = 1; i <= repItem.length; i++) {
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
        rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
        rdbtn.setText(repItem[i-1]);
        ll.addView(rdbtn);
    }
```

The NullPointerException is probably because there is no checked RadioButton in R.id.radiogroupchoi, the checked RadioButton is actually in the RadioGroup that you created and added as a child view to it.

Comment: Samgak, i changed my code as you suggested and it is now working with the addition of Ashish's direction. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this -

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            RadioGroup rChoi=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroupchoi);
            RadioButton butChoi=rChoi.findViewById(rChoi.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),butChoi.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
       });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Ashish fro your quick reply. But i still get NullPointerException on the last line.

Comment: Add xml as well, then i could able to say exactly whats going on.